# Process.CloseMainWindow() doesn't raise Form.Closing event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 different application running at the same time. one is application with hidden form, with no task bar icon only notification icon form
this application is a self host server so it must stays hidden
the second one is agent that start and reset the first application

the main form has event handler added to it:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        this.FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
    }

    private void doDispose()  {
        //Takes time to disconnected
        //about 1 seconds delay
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        doDispose();
    }
```

the code from the agent application (calling reset action on app)

```
private void resetApp() {
                     var process = //get process from Prcesses collection
                        try
                        {


                            process.CloseMainWindow(); <- not raising closing event in the main form
                            process.WaitForExit(1000);
                            process.Close();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }

   }
```

I tried few things from different posts. like, accesing the main model using `process.MainWindowHandle` but because the form is hidden it always return zero.

PS - when closing the first app with the hidden form manually , the event is raised and do the disconnection process as it should. closing it from the second agent application Does not work

thanks

Comment: thanks - but its not in the same application

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you close the form, it may or may not fire the Closing event, see the source of Form.cs at wmClose()

http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/3@5@1/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/NetFXspW7/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form@cs/1/Form@cs

Have you tried overriding the Dispose method?

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    // ...


    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // your code
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: there are 2 application the agent that needs to close the first application - when manually closing the first application the event works

Comment: Try overriding Dispose()